# PHP / CURL snippet standalone works - inside PHP page doesn't

Tags: php, curl

When I run the following code snippet separately it shows the correct result - it is to find out the distance in km between two cities using GoogleMaps Distance Matrix.

If I put exactly the same code into a bigger PHP page (with some MySQL queries to find addresses, with some HTML forms etc.) the result is always "0" !!

```
<?php

$start = "Norderstedt"; // Ulzburger Str. 286, Norderstedt 22850, DE
$ziel = "Neuss"; // Floßhafenstr. 20, Neuss 41460, DE

function curl_request($sURL,$sQueryString=null)
{
        $cURL=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($cURL,CURLOPT_URL,$sURL.'?'.$sQueryString);
        curl_setopt($cURL,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $cResponse=trim(curl_exec($cURL));
        curl_close($cURL);
        return $cResponse;
}

$sResponse=curl_request('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json',
    'origins=' .$start. '&destinations=' .$ziel. '&mode=driving&units=metric&sensor=false');
$oJSON=json_decode($sResponse);
if ($oJSON->status=='OK')
        $fDistanceInKM=(float)preg_replace('/[^\d\.]/','',$oJSON->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text);
else
        $fDistanceInKM=0;

$entfernung = $fDistanceInKM;

echo "Entfernung " .$start. " - " .$ziel. " = " .$entfernung. " km<br>";


?>
```

Any hints ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: you could try running the request through `file_get_contents` instead

Comment: I'ts hard to find an error in code that is working. We need your OTHER code that has the error.

Comment: Check if your MySQL queries _really_ deliver the data that you expect.

Comment: Thanks - but I even put the data in question by hand (without MySQL) to avoid errors like wrong data supplied to the function ...